# ffmpeg image2 avi quality

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm converting a set of images to avi, but the quality is very poor. How can I change the quality of a video?

This is my current command:

```
ffmpeg -i music.wav -f image2 -r 11 -i %%d.png video.avi
```

And you can see a still of the movie [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0djxr.jpg), you can notice the bad quality:

[image]

Comment: Avi is just the container. You need to look at the codec options too. Which codec you use would depend on what kind of device you plan to play back the video on and how large you want the final file to be.

Comment: avi and mpeg you can try for options of codecs. I did the same thing in one of my projects.. Another thing you can try is improve the fps. Even this will have effect on the final output..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't give `ffmpeg` any specific option for the video codec to use, it will choose `mpeg4` with the AVI container.

You can control the quality by setting either of these:

- `-q:v` – choose anything between 1 and 31. Sane values are 3–5, where lower means better quality.
- `-b:v` – choose a bit rate. Start with something around 1 MBit/s, e.g. `-b:v 1M`, and vary this according to your need.

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i music.wav -f image2 -r 11 -i %%d.png -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 3 video.avi
```

I would however recommend you to use the `libx264` encoder (H.264) for better quality per bitrate. Here, you set the quality with:

- `-crf` – anything between 18–28 is a sane choice. Lower means better.
- `-b:v` – like above.

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i music.wav -f image2 -r 11 -i %%d.png -c:v libx264 -crf 20 video.mp4
```

Please [do not use the `sameq` option](https://superuser.com/questions/478549/what-is-the-sameq-or-same-quant-option-in-ffmpeg-does-it-mean-same-quality) – it doesn't mean "same quality".

Answer (score -1):

Add the Same Quality Option : -sameq

This is what I do to convert image from my gopro to a movie :

Excelent Quality
Resize to 1024x768
15 FPS

> ffmpeg -r 15 -i %04d.JPG -s 1024x768 -sameq out.mp4

Comment: This option was removed from `ffmpeg`. It also doesn't mean "same quality" at all. See: [What is the “sameq” or “same_quant” option in FFmpeg?](http://superuser.com/questions/478549/what-is-the-sameq-or-same-quant-option-in-ffmpeg-does-it-mean-same-quality)