# How do I assemble N still images with ffmpeg into a high quality video with anti-alias fonts?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, fonts

I have some nice HD size still images 1920x1080 with beautiful anti-aliased fonts. When I view the still image the fonts are perfect. But when I assemble N of them into a video with:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 29.97 -pattern_type glob -i data/*.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p data/temp.mov
```

The resulting movie doesn't have the fonts looking very nice anymore. What are the best settings to give ffmpeg to keep the fonts looking the best they can?

Update: I tried all the options in [ffmpeg image2 avi quality](https://superuser.com/questions/370058/ffmpeg-image2-avi-quality) and still the fonts never look as great as they do in the still image even with the best quality settings?

Comment: Try, replacing `yuv420p` with `yuv444p`. You may also try higher quality setting as `-crf 17` (add it after `libx264`), but the encoded video file is going to be larger.

Comment: Maybe, you can try with [tune](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Tune) option : `-tune stillimage`

Comment: ahh thanks for these suggestions!